# Connect visual studio to remote docker volume

Tags: visual-studio, docker, ssh, remote-access

I have docker installed on my digital ocean droplet/host running multiple containers.
How can I access the container file system through visual studio code explorer.

I have tried with « Remote Development extension pack » but I am only able to connect/ssh to the host where i have docker installed and running the containers but not the actual containers themselves.

Docker provides the `docker run exec -it` to connect to the CLI of a running container but i am not able to explore the volume / file system of the container through vs code.

Comment: If there is a way to bind the container volume to a folder within my host, this will also works for me.

Comment: In my opinion there is something wrong with your workflow, if you want access droplet folder from your Visual Code studio. I wonder why one would need this.

Comment: @GintsGints i do development works with my local computer. Then, i would commit to github. And finally pull my git update to my container into production. Now i want to be able to make small changes directly into my containers and also be consistent on my IDE. I keep on switching between ‘nano’ and ‘visual studio’. Do you have any recommendations ?